# Error in Elastic Search in Javasctipt - Querying against multiple indexes

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

When I run the below code I'm running the following in error in elastic search:

`Invalid alias name [...] must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]`

It doesn't like that I'm using `index1,index2` as my index (I've also tried `index : [index1, index2]`

This code works in Kibana when I run it against the same data source.

Elastic Search dependency is `"@elastic/elasticsearch": "7.6"`

```
  const { client } = context; // context from graphql resolver

  const query = buildQuery({
    id: id,
    queryIndex: `${index1},${index2}`;
  });

  const results = await client.search(query);

  export const buildQuery = ({ id. queryIndex }) => ({
      index: queryIndex,
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                terms: {
                  'someId': [id]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        aggs: {
          byindex: {
            terms: {
              field: '_index'
            },
            aggs: {
              min_date: {
                min: {
                  field: 'date',
                  format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                }
              },
              max_date: {
                max: {
                  field: 'date',
                  format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you itself having the solution 
the index should be an array of strings instead of a string

[reference link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/414#issuecomment-226079280)